# dict as class property seems to be same for all instances

Tags: python

I recognize strange behavior in my code. I extract some testcode to demonstrate:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.mystr = 'A'
        self.mydict['key'] = 'value'

class B(A):
    mystr = 'B'
    mydict = {}
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name, 'mystr (before)', self.mystr)
        print(name, 'mydict (before)', self.mydict)
        super().__init__()
        print(name, 'mystr (after)', self.mystr)
        print(name, 'mydict (after)', self.mydict)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    b1 = B('b1')
    b2 = B('b2')
```

The output is:

```
b1 mystr (before) B
b1 mydict (before) {}
b1 mystr (after) A
b1 mydict (after) {'key': 'value'}
b2 mystr (before) B
b2 mydict (before) {'key': 'value'}  // <- I expect this to be {}
b2 mystr (after) A
b2 mydict (after) {'key': 'value'}
```

The property `mystr` works as I expected. For the second instance `b2` it is 'B' as it was initialized. But the property `mydict` is not initialized correct for the second instance and contains the key/value pair:

> b2 mydict (before) {'key': 'value'}

I know that there a mutable and immutable variables in Python and that the first one are hold by reference. But I can explain, why my code is not working as expected.

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have a single dict shared by all instance of the class. The key is that

```
self.mydict['key'] = 'value'
```

is not an assignment to the attribute `mydict`, so it does not create a new instance attribute. Rather, it's a method call

```
self.mydict.__setitem__('key', 'value')
```

and the lookup `self.mydict` resolves to `A.mydict` since there is no *instance* attribute named `mydict`.

On the other hand,

```
self.mystr = 'A'
```

*is* an assignment to an attribute, so it always creates a new instance attribute if it does not already exist, rather than changing the value of an existing class attribute of the same name. If you want to change the value of a class attribute via an instance of the class, you have to first get a reference to the class, with something like

```
self.__class__.mystr = 'A'  # Modifies A.mystr without creating self.mystr instead
```

Comment: I see that I define class attributes - I understand. And with self.mystr = ... I create a instance attribute, that shadows the class attribute, right?

Comment: Correct. There's an asymmetry between class and instance attributes. Accessing an attribute via an instance can fall back to accessing a class attribute, but assigning to an attribute via an instance *always* creates the instance attribute if it does not exist.